# vb.net RegEx not works as expected

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to use RegEx to validate user input, the input format should be :

partA/partB

partA: number(number of digit is a variable)

partB: 2 digit number

I use the workable expression in Flex in vb.net, but not work.

My code is like follows:

```
    If Not Regex.Match(ItemNo.Text, "/\d\{2\}$").Success Then
       ItemNo.Text = "Invalid Contract No."
       ItemNo.Focus()
       Return
End If
```

Could anybody help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: what you are actually trying to achieve? what is your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your regex to,

```
^\d+/\d{2}$
```

So the code would be,

```
If Not Regex.Match(ItemNo.Text, "^\d+/\d{2}$").Success Then
       ItemNo.Text = "Invalid Contract No."
       ItemNo.Focus()
       Return
End If
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits where `\d{2}` matches exactly two digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d*\/\d{2}$
```

You should try this.This will get vairable forst partand 2 digit second part.